# How to use ImportExport Import Model in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, event-observer, importexport

I want to use  ImportExport Import Model. I want to convert the code below to Magento 2.

In Magento 1, it uses:

```
Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::getDataSourceModel()->getIterator()->rewind();
```

Comment: Write more detail. M2 import&export module almost brand new. It's lot's improvement.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. This single line without context does nothing. You need to show more code to get help with converting.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, we can follow:

```
\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import::getDataSourceModel()->getIterator()->rewind()
```

Comment: Thanks!
I also want to use code ($adapter instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product) in Magento2. Can you please help me for this.

Comment: Seem that it is a different issue. Should ask new question.